# Python : Dot product of dask array

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py, dask

I am trying to do dot product of very large 2 dask arrays X (35000 x 7500) and Y(7500 x 10). As the dot product will also be very large I am storing it in hdf5

```
f = h5py.File('output.hdf5')
f['output'] = X.dot(Y)
```

But the second command is not giving any output even though its almost 1 hour. What is wrong? Is there faster technique ? Is there issue of "chunks" while creating X and Y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the `.to_hdf5` method or `da.store` function.

```
>>> X.dot(Y).to_hdf5('output.hdf5', 'output')
```

or

```
>>> output = f.create_dataset('/output', X.dot(Y).shape, X.dot(Y).dtype)
>>> da.store(X.dot(Y), output)
```

The `to_hdf5` method is probably easier for  you.  The `da.store` method is general to other formats as well.

The `__setitem__` function in H5Py (what you're using when you say `f['output'] = ...` is hardcoded to use NumPy arrays.

[Here is the appropriate section in the documentation.](http://dask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/array-overview.html#store)

Comment: Sir I saw your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34434217/why-is-dot-product-in-dask-slower-than-in-numpy) . So how do i know what type of chunking is best for me?

Comment: The to_hdf5 method will chunk your dataset similar to how your dask.array is chunked.  I recommend just using that.

Comment: My X is of float32 and Y float96. It is showing me "TypeError: Unsupported float size " . Any clues?

Comment: I wasn't aware that NumPy supported dtype float96.  Perhaps try float64 or 128?

Comment: I changed to float64. It says "ValueError: Chunks do not align"

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to give a clearer explanation of what's happening.  Hopefully a small example that reproduces the error that I can try myself.

Comment: .to_hdf5() worked by restarting shell . But now I am facing another problem. I got very large dask array yHat. Now "yHat[0][0].compute()" or "yHat[0].compute()" isn't working. It freezes my shell and keyboard interrupt is also not working.

Comment: I recommend starting a new stackoverflow question for your new issue.