# Runtime comparison of Dask and NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, dask

I am trying to restructure my code to use Dask instead of NumPy for large array computations. However, I am struggling with the runtime performance of Dask:

```
In[15]: import numpy as np
In[16]: import dask.array as da
In[17]: np_arr = np.random.rand(10, 10000, 10000)
In[18]: da_arr = da.from_array(np_arr, chunks=(-1, 'auto', 'auto'))
In[19]: %timeit np.mean(np_arr, axis=0)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.59 s per loop
In[20]: %timeit da_arr.mean(axis=0).compute()
1 loop, best of 3: 4.23 s per loop
```

I had a look at similar questions ([why is dot product in dask slower than in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34434217/why-is-dot-product-in-dask-slower-than-in-numpy)), but playing around with the chunk size did not help. I will mainly use arrays having approximately the same size as above. Is it recommendable to use NumPy instead of Dask for such arrays or can I tune something? I have also tried to use the `Client` from `dask.distributed` and started it with 16 processes and 4 threads per process (16 core CPU), but this made it even worse. 
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I have played a bit around with Dask and distributed processing. The data transfer (dumping of array and retrieval of result) seems to be the major limitation/issue, whereas computation is really fast (436ms compared to 9.51s). But even for `client.compute()`, the wall time is larger (12.1s) than for `do_stuff(data)`. Can this and the data transfer in general somehow be improved?

```
In[3]: import numpy as np
In[4]: from dask.distributed import Client, wait
In[5]: from dask import delayed
In[6]: import dask.array as da
In[7]: client = Client('address:port')
In[8]: client
Out[8]: <Client: scheduler='tcp://address:port' processes=4 cores=16>
In[9]: data = np.random.rand(400, 100, 10000)
In[10]: %time [future] = client.scatter([data])
CPU times: user 8.36 s, sys: 5.08 s, total: 13.4 s
Wall time: 24.5 s
In[11]: x = da.from_delayed(delayed(future), shape=data.shape, dtype=data.dtype)
In[12]: x = x.rechunk(chunks=('auto', 'auto', 'auto'))
In[13]: x = client.persist(x)
In[14]: {w: len(keys) for w, keys in client.has_what().items()}
Out[14]: 
{'tcp://address:port': 65,
 'tcp://address:port': 0,
 'tcp://address:port': 0,
 'tcp://address:port': 0}
In[15]: client.rebalance(x)
In[16]: {w: len(keys) for w, keys in client.has_what().items()}
Out[16]: 
{'tcp://address:port': 17,
 'tcp://address:port': 16,
 'tcp://address:port': 16,
 'tcp://address:port': 16}
In[17]: def do_stuff(arr):
...         arr = arr/3. + arr**2 - arr**(1/2)
...         arr[arr >= 0.5] = 1
...         return arr
...   
In[18]: %time future_compute = client.compute(do_stuff(x)); wait(future_compute)
Matplotlib support failed
CPU times: user 387 ms, sys: 49.5 ms, total: 436 ms
Wall time: 12.1 s
In[19]: future_compute
Out[19]: <Future: status: finished, type: ndarray, key: finalize-54eb04bbe03eee8af686fd43b41eb161>
In[21]: %timeit future_compute.result()
1 loop, best of 3: 19.4 s per loop
In[21]: %time do_stuff(data)
CPU times: user 4.49 s, sys: 5.02 s, total: 9.51 s
Wall time: 9.5 s
```

Comment: Hello clax. Parallelization doesn't speed up every tasks. Sometimes it is slower to create multiple processes for doing simple stuff. I suggest you to try a more complex task than just compute a mean.

Comment: Hi @CorentinLimier, thanks for your comment! I am aware that dask multiprocessing is not the right choice for simple tasks (due to data dumping and data distribution between workers). I have only mentioned the parallel processing that one knows that I have tried it. But shouln't Dask yield the approximate runtime as NumPy, when using the exact same environment and optimal chunks? Leaving multiprocessing aside, is it then better to stick to NumPy in case of simple computations along an axis of arrays such above?

Comment: You might want to read [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-i-learned-to-love-parallelized-applies-with-python-pandas-dask-and-numba-f06b0b367138)

Comment: Thank you @user32185 for this useful link! I did not know about Numba and I will try to use it too. However I am still curious if it is possible to improve the performance with Dask.